# Vista update fails: component store corrupted

Tags: windows-vista, update

I have a vista x64 box that is no longer able to apply updates from microsoft.  When I dig in looking for the problem I find this in the event log "could not be installed because of an error: 2147956498 "The component store has been corrupted.""  I cannot get system restore to go back far enough to escape the problem.

Can you think of a way to fix this machine, or do I have to do a complete wipe and rebuild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it sounded promising the tool suggested by Martin did not work.  (It refused to install).  More research lead to knowledge base article [946414](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946414) which has a link to a windows update FixIt tool.  The FixIt tool when run with the most aggressive(not recommended) setting fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft provide a tool to repair a corrupted component store:

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=947821

More techy details here:

http://kurtsh.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!DA410C7F7E038D!2798.entry

Comment: This appears to be the answer.  But, the suggested utility failed on first run complaining that I needed to update some other windows installer component.  When I eventually get it running, I'll accept the answer.  But fixing this box is always about #17 on my todo list.

Comment: Good luck, and keep us posted.